# Does Mizzix/Reiterate/Electrodominance infinite loop work?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-stack

In theory, you use the experience counters on [Mizzix of the Izmagnus](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mizzix%20of%20the%20Izmagnus) to pay for the Buyback cost of [Reiterate](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Reiterate) to remove it from the graveyard, allowing you to recast [Electrodominance](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Electrodominance).

But, all that does is put Reinterate in your hand.  It doesn’t cover the cost of the 2Red for the spell, right?  Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

There is a loop here, but not the one you describe. Buyback does not "remove [the card] from the graveyard", it is an additional cost you pay while casting a spell, to make it go back into your hand after it resolves. The other key here is that Electrodominance allows you to cast a spell for free, and that spell can be Reiterate. That's what pays for Reiterate's cost.

Here's how the loop works:

- You start with Mizzix, at least 3 experience counters, and at least RRRR in mana.
- You cast Electrodominance for X=3, paying RR.
- If you have 4 or fewer experience counters, Mizzix's ability triggers, giving you another one
- In response to Electrodominance, you cast Reiterate with buyback targeting Electrodominance, paying RR.
- Reiterate resolves, and makes a copy of Electrodominance, and goes back into your hand because of buyback.
- The copy of Electrodominance resolves, dealing 3 damage to its target, and you can cast a spell with mana value 3 or less without paying its mana cost. You choose to cast Reiterate, and you choose to pay for buyback. Buyback increases the cost by 3, and Mizzix reduces the cost by at least 3, so you don't have to pay any mana.
- Reiterate resolves, and makes a copy of Electrodominance, and goes back into your hand because of buyback.

You can keep doing this as long as you want, dealing as much damage as you want to any number of targets.

Comment: You actually only need RRRR since Electrodominance with X=3 will give you another experience counter.

Comment: I've updated the answer to cover that

Comment: You could also mention that the worse-case scenario (0 XP counters) leads to only needing 7 mana more (3 electro, 3 first reiterate, 1 second reiterate), but that's kinda outside the question.

Comment: My goal here was to explain the basic case to illustrate how the combo works in general, rather than to explore every variation of the combo. The confusion in the question was not about the specific numbers needed to reach an infinite, but rather about the basic functionality of the buyback ability.

Comment: Reiterate going back to the hand is a deliberate part of the combo. That's what allows you to cast it using the effect of Electrodominance.

Comment: Definitely, the worst-case scenario is just reiterating (see what I did there) the basic answer, so not including it is fine.